# Remove side menu(right side) from finder

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

When I open any Finder window it appears with options in the right side. I can hide it by dragging it to end. But if I open a new window of the finder it appears again. So, please help me to hide that options menu in Finder.

**OS: Mojave 10.14.5**

[image: Finder Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the screenshot I posted, You'll see what you need to click in order to disable the preview in your Finder.
My OS is in French and I don't know the name of the option in English, that's why I sent this screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is View-> Show Preview. Any idea how to make it permanent if it isn't already?

Comment: In the screenshot, the highlighted option is 'activate' of course, I disabled it to test if that's what you where looking for. :-)

Comment: It should normally be permanent when you change the option.

Answer (score 3):

You can click **Finder** > **View** > **Hide Preview** or just press **⇧⌘P** when in column view. Changing the setting acts on all opened **Finder** windows  and all subsequent **Finder** windows until one clicks **Finder** > **View** > **Show Preview** or presses **⇧⌘P** again when in column view.